# Server side event for button in sandbox solution

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sandbox-solution

i am developing one sandbox solution. i have one .aspx page in my solution, there i need to create one button and need to write server-side event for that button. But i couldn't do it. getting error as "The event handler 'OnClick' is not allowed in this page."

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" %>
<html dir="ltr" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">`

    <head>
    </head>

    <body>

        <form id="form1" runat="server">

            <asp:Button ID="btnClick" Text="Click Me" runat="server"
             OnClick="Btn_Click" /> 

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can't we add server-side event for controls in sandbox solution.?

Answer (score 2):

You can't use Application Pages in Sandboxed Solutions. See [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798382.aspx) from Microsoft regarding what components are allowed in Sandboxed Solutions.

An alternative to what you are doing, would be to create a Web Part. If you create and deploy a custom Web Part, you can deploy code, create buttons etc. Make sure not to create a *Visual* Web Part, though, as these are not supported.